# Where can I find additional TFS 2010 Process Guidance templates?

Tags: tfs

Does anyone know where I can find any process guidance templates for TFS 2010 other than the two provided by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Project creation wizard also has a link to download more Microsoft certified process templates, link which points to this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718795.aspx. Make sure you keep an eye on that site as new templates will be posted there.

Thanks, Ladislau

Answer (score 1):

Version 3 of the Scrum for Team System template (currenlty a release candidate at time of writing) is available.  Info and download locations are available at http://scrumforteamsystem.com/cs/forums/14/ShowForum.aspx

I'm not sure where some of the older 2008 templates on codeplex are up to in terms of providing 2010 versions.  I'd suggest going to codeplex and searching for TFS and template and seeing what you find.